# SQL Server, Duplicate subquery, and Alias

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple query as the following:

```
Select SUBSTRING(Email, Charindex('@', Email) + 1,
    Len(Email) - CharIndex('@', Email)) as EmailDomain,
    Count(Email) as Total
from tblPerson
Group by SUBSTRING(Email, Charindex('@', Email) + 1,
Len(Email) - CharIndex('@', Email))
```

Which is working fine except that there is a subquery duplicate:

```
SUBSTRING(Email, Charindex('@', Email) + 1,
Len(Email) - CharIndex('@', Email))
```

I have put an alias for the sub-query there `as EmailDomain`, but when I query like this:

```
Select SUBSTRING(Email, Charindex('@', Email) + 1,
    Len(Email) - CharIndex('@', Email)) as EmailDomain,
    Count(Email) as Total
from tblPerson
Group by EmailDomain
```

I got an error:

> Invalid column name 'EmailDomain'

How to fix this but also at the same time not using duplicate query?

Comment: This is because you `select` statement is parsed after your `group by` clause. So if you use alias in `select` query, it will not be identified by `group by`. The main query you gave earlier is the best way to go about it rather than using subquery.

Comment: @Utsav ah, thanks. I think I get it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple you can not use column alias in WHERE clause or GROUP BY clause.

You can try like this:

```
SELECT EmailDomain,
       Total 
FROM (
        Select SUBSTRING(Email, Charindex('@', Email) + 1,
        Len(Email) - CharIndex('@', Email)) as EmailDomain,
        Count(Email) as Total
        from tblPerson
        ) a
Group by EmailDomain
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the alias in the `GROUP BY`. To fix this, you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT
    t.EmailDomain,
    COUNT(t.Email) AS Total
FROM (
    SELECT
        SUBSTRING(Email, CHARINDEX('@', Email) + 1, LEN(Email) - CHARINDEX('@', Email)) AS EmailDomain,
        Email
    FROM tblPerson
) t
GROUP BY t.EmailDomain
```

Comment: ah, thanks I get it, the subquery must be done that way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

TRY WITH BELOW SCRIPT:

```
Select EmailDomain from (Select SUBSTRING(Email, Charindex('@', Email) + 1,
    Len(Email) - CharIndex('@', Email)) as EmailDomain,
    Count(Email) as Total
from tblPerson) tperson
Group by EmailDomain
```